# req.params llega como objeto vacío

Tags: nodejs, jsonwebtoken

Estoy implementando un proceso de recuperación de contraseña pero al requerir el token que viene por `req.params` no lo puedo obtener, req.params viene como un objeto vacío `{}`
Esta es la petición del frontend:

```
let options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { "Content-Type": "Application/json" }
  }
  fetch('http://localhost:3001/reset-password/:id/:token', options)
    .then(response => {
      console.log("Response --->>> ", response)
      if (response.status === 200) {
        setResetpassword(true)
      }
    })
```

Este es el sevidor(nodejs) que recibe la petición:

```
app.use('/reset-password/:id/:token', require('./routes/olvidoPassword/resetPassword'))
```

Y este es el código que verifica el token: **resetPassword.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router({mergeParams:true})
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const JWT_SECRTET = "some super secret..."

router.get('/', (req, res) => {          
    let { id, token } = req.params
    console.log("id ",id)
    console.log("token ",token)
    console.log("req.params -->> ",req.params)    
    jwt.verify(token, JWT_SECRTET, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("err-->> ", err)
            res.status(400).send('No Ok')
            //return
        }
        else {
            res.status(200).send('ok')
            //return
        }
    })
})
module.exports = router
```

Pero el `console.log("req.params -->> ",req.params)` arroja `req.params -->>  {}`

Agradezco alguna ayuda.

Comment: Pero la petición del front debería reemplazar las variables valores por sus respectivos valores en la URL, si lo está haciendo? (En tu código de ejemplo eso no es muy claro)

Comment: Correcto. Eso voy a intentar.

Answer (score 0):

En la URL de la petición que se hace desde el frontend debe especificar los parámetros que viene por req.params `http://localhost:3001/reset-password/${id}/${token}. Y debe capturar los parámetros con el hook useParams` const {id,token} = useParams()`